# Jenkins - Maven error - Could not find or load main class

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

I am trying to run maven project using Jenkins for the first time and I am getting the following the error in Jenkins - console O/P.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MAVEN_HOME
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

My POM

I am able to run the maven project in eclipse successfully

```
<i>    
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aig.cucumberwork</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.aig.cucumberwork</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency> 
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>   
  </dependencies>
</project>
</i>
```

```
Maven build 
Root POM : C:\Users\marajend\test\com.aig.cucumberwork\pom.xml
```

I am able to run the maven project in eclipse successfully

Comment: did you add MVN in the tools section ?

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten a `$` somewhere in Jenkins? MAVEN_HOME should be a variable, not a string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the error you are seeing **`Error: Could not find or load main class MAVEN_HOME`** is clear and concise. You need to check the following steps :

- Within the `Environment Variables` create a `User Variable` as, **`MAVEN_HOME`** with a valid value e.g. **`C:\apache-maven-3.3.3`**
- Within **`Jenkins Configuration`** you have to mention **`MAVEN_HOME`** again with the same valid value e.g. **`C:\apache-maven-3.3.3`**

Comment: I think the older versions of **`Jenkins`** made it mandatory to create a variable by some name (I preferred **`MAVEN_HOME`**) which will point to the `Maven Installation Directory`. Hence to avoid creating duplicate `constants`, **`MAVEN_HOME`** looks pretty logical to me.

Comment: Upvote this/any Answer which is/was useful to you for the future readers.

Comment: First if you define a MAVEN_HOME variable this will point to a particular location usually on MASTER which is not enough. If you correctly go via Jenkins Tool Location (which is there for a long time) it will work on Master only in the first place. If you configure to use auto installer via the Jenkins Tool Locations it will work on any node...automatically. So the definition of MAVEN_HOME is simply wrong...This is also true for pipeline code and Maven Job type...